# Add header text to merged regions ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I crop 2 regions from source image to merge them in pairs and then add a header centered at the top that says "Left Right" with red background. For this I have this code that uses the source input.png and LeftRight.png as helper.

This is the **Input.png**

[image: input.png]

This is the helper image I use to create the header **LeftRight.png**

[image: LeftRight.png]

The code so far:

```
convert input.png \ 
-write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor black \ 
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+462+176 \) \   ( mpr:img -crop 240x151+87+257  \) \ 
+smush +6 LeftRight.png +swap -gravity   center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-A.png    \) -delete 0--1 \ 
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+468+542 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+140+624 \) \ 
+smush +6 LeftRight.png +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-B.png \) null:
```

I generate this 2 images with the code:

[image: Img-A.png]

[image: Img-B.png]

How can be modified this part

```
+smush +6 LeftRight.png +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write
```

in order to add a header text "Left Rigth" with same characteristics without using the helper image **LeftRight.png** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your text image first in ImageMagick, then save to mpr: to use later. See my 2nd - 4th lines.

Note your input.png got changed to JPG.

```
convert \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "LEFT" \) \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "RIGHT" \) \
-background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
input.jpg +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor black \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+462+176 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+87+257 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-A.png \) -delete 0--1 \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+468+542 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+140+624 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-B.png \) null:
```

[image]

[image]

Your -bordercolor black does nothing here since you have not added -border x.  I have included -border 2 to put the border around the cropped images. Also your -delete 0--1 could be replaced here with simply +delete since there is only one image created to be deleted in this example.

ADDITION:

You asked to resize the images to 380x150. You can do that as follows. But note that the aspect of the original cropped images are not the same as 380x150. So to get exactly 380x150 without losing data by keeping the aspect ratio or padding, I have to distort the resulting cropped images to fit exactly to 380x150. See where I put -resize 380x150!. The "!" tells ImageMagick to distort the image to fit exactly to your 380x150

```
convert \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "LEFT" \) \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "RIGHT" \) \
-background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
input.jpg +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor black \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+462+176 +repage -resize 380x150! -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+87+257 +repage -resize 380x150! -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-A.png \) -delete 0--1 \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+468+542 +repage -resize 380x150! -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+140+624 +repage -resize 380x150! -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-B.png \) null:
```

[image]

[image]

ADDITION 2:

If you want to resize the appended pairs of cropped images, then put the resize right after both +smush 6, which append the two images. Note again the results may be distorted, since I forced it to fit the exact size. If you do not want distortion, then you must specify whether you want the image cropped or padded or just fit to the width or the height.

```
convert \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "LEFT" \) \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "RIGHT" \) \
-background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
input.jpg +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor black \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+462+176 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+87+257 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 -resize 380x150! mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-A.png \) -delete 0--1 \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+468+542 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+140+624 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 -resize 380x150! mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -write Img-B.png \) null:
```

[image]

[image]

ADDITION 3:

If you want to resize the two final output images, then put the resize command just before you write those images.

```
convert \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "LEFT" \) \
\( -size 159x24 xc:"#7f0000" -fill white -font ubuntu -pointsize 18 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "RIGHT" \) \
-background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
input.jpg +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor black \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+462+176 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+87+257 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -resize 380x150! -write Img-A.png \) -delete 0--1 \
\( \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+468+542 +repage -border 2 \) \( mpr:img -crop 240x151+140+624 +repage -border 2 \) \
+smush +6  mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +3 +gravity -resize 380x150! -write Img-B.png \) null:
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi fmw42, thanks for your answer. It seems to work perfect. Nice to learn a little bit each time from experts. I've added a 2x2 border but still there is not border in the output. I did like this  `-background none -bordercolor black - border 2x2`

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the black border. I did not notice the black border earlier in our example. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: No issue fmw42. It works just amazing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi again fmw42, the resulting images have a size of 494x182. Where in the code should be added ` -resize 380x150` ? In order to change to that size each image? Thanks

Comment: `@Ger Cas` See my addition to my earlier answer. If you do not want to distort the cropped image, you must tell me whether you want the cropped image to be center cropped to your dimensions when resizing or padded when resizing.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I see you added `-resize 380x150!` after each crop, so each cropped image would have that size. I'm more interested in know how to resize the resulting image generated from merge the first and second crop, I mean, how to resize at the end the Img-A.png and Img-B.png to 380x150. I hope make sense.

Comment: `@Ger Cas` See my ADDITION 2.

Comment: `fmw42` I followed your second addition but the new size is 380x177. I think I didn't explain correctly. I would like to resize to 389x150 the complete resulting image, this is the 2 appended pairs of cropped images plus the header text (left-right) The 2 cropped images plus the header text are part of the same resulting image (Img-A.png and Img-B.png) So I want to resize the resulting image built from the header text and 2 cropped images. Thanks again for the help

Comment: `@Ger Cas` See my ADDITION 3